# There is already an extension called security in the Custom Binding Element. Extension names must be unique

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to make a WCF Service which passes data back to the Client. But I want to encrypt this. So I did this in the Web.Config

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="message">
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" />
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Sha256" />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

But I'm getting this error back: There is already an extension called security in the Custom Binding Element. Extension names must be unique. I can't seem to find anything that answers my question.

Comment: The error message doesn't match what you say you've done. Have you added anything to `system.serviceModel>extensions>behaviorExtensions`?

Comment: @DavidG I've not. They only thing I got there is diagnostics but that shouldn't interfere.

Comment: <security /> is more than one time declared.

Comment: @Rabban Yes I saw it just now. Thank you for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me used two times the `<security>` tag and thats why the conflict.

I found my answer with this link: https://forums.asp.net/t/1754661.aspx?Message+Security+Certificate+ProtectionLevel+None+Need+explaination+